# table-cell looks like ignore the fixed width

Tags: html, css

my construction:

```
<div style="display: table;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 50px; background-color: red;">a</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 100%; background-color: green;">...</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 50px; background-color: red;">a</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5PgzT/

edge columns should be remain 50px width, still its like I didnt set anything

Comment: Why not just use a table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the parent `<div>` doesn't have an explicit `width`, Also you'll probably need to use [`table-layout: fixed;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) as well:

```
<div style="display: table; width: 100%; table-layout: fixed;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 50px; background-color: red;">a</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 100%; background-color: green;">...</div>
    <div style="display: table-cell; width: 50px; background-color: red;">a</div>
</div>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/5PgzT/1/)**

Comment: Or (less elegant solution) you can use `min-width:50px` instead

Answer (score 2):

What's happening here is the center table-cell is stretching to 100% of an undefined value. Try giving the table a width and letting the center cell sort itself out, instead of being defined:

```
<div style="display:table; width:400px;">
    <div style="display:table-cell; width:50px; background-color: red;">&nbsp;</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell; background-color: green; width:auto;">content</div>
    <div style="display:table-cell; width:50px; background-color: red;">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```